# What is a spark kernel for apache toree?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter, apache-toree

I have a spark cluster which master is on 192.168.0.60:7077

I used to use jupyter notebook to make some pyspark scripts.
I am now willing to move on to scala.
I don't know scala's world.
I am trying to use Apache Toree.
I installed it, downloaded the scala kernels, and runned it to the point to open a scala notebook . Till there everything seems ok :-/

But I can't find the spark context, and there are errors in the jupyter's server logs :

```
[I 16:20:35.953 NotebookApp] Kernel started: afb8cb27-c0a2-425c-b8b1-3874329eb6a6
Starting Spark Kernel with SPARK_HOME=/Users/romain/spark
Error: Master must start with yarn, spark, mesos, or local
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
[I 16:20:38.956 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
```

As I don't know scala, I am not sure of the issue here ?
It could be :

1. I need a spark kernel (according to https://github.com/ibm-et/spark-kernel/wiki/Getting-Started-with-the-Spark-Kernel )
2. I need to add an option on the server (the error message says 'Master must start with yarn, spark, mesos, or local' )
3. or something else :-/

I was just willing to migrate from python to scala, and I spend a few hours lost just on starting up the jupyter IDE :-/

Comment: never used jupyter, so don't know about #1, but your master should be configured to `spark://192.168.0.60:7077`. Spark has several supported "cluster managers" or deployment modes - to indicate that you're using 'standalone" mode (i.e. a Spark master was setup and is listening on port 7077) you use a URL with `spark` protocol.

Comment: Check [spark configuration for apache toree](https://toree.apache.org/documentation/user/installation.html#configuring-spark). Did you installed same way?

Comment: Yes I did follow the online install documentation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Spark in a standalone deploy mode. As Tzach suggested in his comment, following should work:

```
SPARK_OPTS='--master=spark://192.168.0.60:7077' jupyter notebook
```

`SPARK_OPTS` expects usual `spark-submit` parameter list.

If that does not help, you would need to check the `SPARK_MASTER_PORT` value in `conf/spark-env.sh` (7077 is the default).